# Turning A premise into Code?

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics

I have this assignment that requires me to turn a premise statement into code. The idea is that i need to print out the truth table for a premise statement.
This is the premise: 
 (((P v Q) ^ (Q -> R)) XOR (P v R)) <-> (R ^ Q)

I can create a manual Truth table [Truth Table for the above premise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHDwX.png)

I just dont understand how to transform that into code? How would i approach that using the typical basic libraries such as iostream, string, math, etc. I can't utilize anything else like vectors, sets, etc.

You don't have to write literal code but perhaps some pseudocode might help or even justs tips.

I understand that "^" is &&, "v" is ||, "->" is "if-else" but i'm not sure about "<->" and "XOR" or simply how to put that in code.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
As per the assistance of my fellow stackoverflow peers, we've managed to obtain the literal meaning of each logical operator statement into a c++ approach.

```
(P v Q)   = P OR Q           = (P || Q)
(P ^ Q)   = P AND Q          = (P && Q)
(P XOR Q) = P ^ Q            = (P ^ Q)
(P -> Q)  = if P then Q      = (!P || Q)
(p <-> Q) = Only If P then Q = !(P ^ Q)
```

Comment: The symbol `^` is the XOR operator.

Comment: A implies B can be rewritten as (NOT A) or B.

Comment: What is the definition of `<->`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I would say that <-> is XNOR

Comment: I though that ^ means OR. What does "^" mean then? According to my notes "<->" means "If not q then not p", "If p then p" as for code, i have no idea.

Comment: @RSon1234 so your saying that "(NOT A) or B" can be written as ((!A) || B)?

Comment: ^ is XOR in c++

Comment: @JonathanVazquez yes that is what I am saying

Comment: @scohe001 could you elaborate why "^" is not OR in C++? What would take over for that "^" logical operator?

Comment: @scohe001 Isn't ^ "AND" in formal logic?

Comment: @RSon1234 I think i made a mistake as well, "v" should be XOR not "^"

Comment: @JonathanVazquez "v" is OR in formal logic and || in c++.  "^" is AND in formal and && in c++.  XOR is ⊻ or ⊕ in formal logic and ^ in c++

Comment: Check the second to last line of your truth table. Try to simplify the formula. It is equal to e. g. `(P && !Q) || (!P && !R)`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin are you referring to this statement: "(P -> Q)  = if P then Q      = (!P || Q)"

Comment: Upvoted, cause I think it's ridiculous to have 5 down votes for this question. It is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use Boolean variables:

```
// declare variables and initialize.
bool p = true;
bool q = true;
bool r = true;
// Input values (from user or file)
//...

// Output some columns:
cout << p << " | " << q << " | " << r << " | ";
cout << (p || q) << " | ";
//...
cout << endl;
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. How does this address the OP's question?

Comment: This shows an example of turning some logic operations into code.  Also, it demonstrates outputting the first 4  columns of the example truth table.

Comment: Thank You that makes sense. I'll try to do a single premise statement in boolean to test the waters. I'll post back with my example.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews okay so i'm working on figuring out "if p then q" which is "p->q". I have this statement (!p || q). Which gives the right value in the truth table until i go to row 2. Which should be False not TRUE.

Comment: @JonathanVazquez p -> q and !p or q are logically equivalent

Comment: @RSon1234 your right idk why i though i was wrong. Now for "<->" which is "If not q then not p" || "if p then q". I tried using (!p && !q) which works for all rows in the truth table except for True which i get a returning 0. can this statements be really long? or they relatively small?

Comment: @JonathanVazquez <-> is just XNOR.  so it is just NOT(p XOR q).  In C++ it would be !(p ^ q)

Comment: @RSon1234 So i tried !(p || q) but the its not outputting a 1 for both T | T and F | F. Instead its outputting a 1 for F | T and  T | F.

Comment: @JonathanVazquez Edit your original question with the code you've written. More likely than not, there are some larger errors here...

Comment: @JonathanVazquez don't use ||.  Use ^ as i said above

Comment: @scohe001 i dont have code yet, i'm still trying to convert logical operators into their appropriate code. Once i have them all, i'll post them here so others can use them as reference.

Comment: @RSon1234 apologies, idk why i wrote || in the comment above. Either way its doesnt work with "^". When i have !(0 && 0) my answer ends up been FALSE, when it should be TRUE.

Comment: @JonathanVazquez now you are using &&?  Stop confusing formal and c++.  Literally type !(p ^ q).  use the symbol ^ in your code. I am not saying and

Comment: @scohe001 i thought the statement would of been !(0 && 0) -> !(1) since both sides of the "&&" are the same making the statement TRUE. and whats NOT(1), well its (0).

Comment: @RSon1234 honestly i didn't even know that ^ was an operator to use. I just looked it up and its a bitwise operator, never used bitwise operators in my programming classes. This is a first, and its appreciated. I need to go back and learn those operators. Thanks, i think i have enough to go ahead and program my premise.

Comment: @JonathanVazquez "since both sides...are the same" that would be true if we were talking about an XOR (`^` in c++), but you're using AND there...